# How to read unique key in spring for every request

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have requirement to access a particular variable in every service and dao classes. This variable is generated in controller class and passed to service layer and dao layer.

e.g. in Service layer : getService(String key)
in Dao : getTable(String key)

This key is basically used to store error codes in a map with the reference of the key. This key is generated for each service when the request is received in the server. This key is a random number.

Is there a way to fetch this key from spring context so that it can be fetched every time it is required to be used, Instead of passing it every where.

Comment: Why not just pass through the key when you call the service layer from the controller, and when you call teh repository layer from the service layer?

Comment: Would storing the variable in a [ThreadLocal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) work for you?

Comment: Instead of doing it in traditional way we want to use features available in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to pass the value via method argument through each layer. If you are trying to minimize the number of arguments in you methods, it is better to [Introduce a Parameter Object](http://refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html).

However, if all the beans that required the value of variable are defined with [Request Scope](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-request), then you could define a `VariableHolder<T>` bean to store the value of the variable.

The controller with call `variableHolder.set(value)` and all the other beans will call `variableHolder.get()` to obtain it.